# Facebook API: Get Customized Conversion ID associated to an AdSet.

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to get the the id of the customized conversion associated to an Ad Set using the Facebook Marketing API. Unfortunately I haven't found the way to do that.

I've assigned a customized conversion (Concierge-Thanks, ID: 123456) to an Ad Set. I'm trying to get this value (ID: 123456) using the Marketing API but I haven't been able to find where FB stores the association between the Ad Set and the associated Customized Conversion.

[Customized Conversion associated to an Ad Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7wWZ.png)
[Customized Conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oitT7.png)